# Create a link in Twig with translate filter

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm trying to create an email link with only Twig tags. I've read numerous posts here but I can't get this one working! The problem I'm facing is that a string must get a translate filter in it.

The link itself is for email purpose.

So what I try to make is a link like this:

http://www.website.com/service/?subject=1234&message=Desired+amount

So what I tried is this:

```
{{ ('service?subject=' ~ product.code | url_encode) | url }} // This works perfectly
```

Now I want to add the `&message` part, so what I did is this:

```
{{ ('service?subject=' ~ product.code  ~ '&message=' ~ (Desired amount | t) | url_encode) | url }}
```

As you can see the `Desired amount` needs to have a translate tag (which is `t` by the way).

Offcourse this doesn't work.

Does anybody know how to create such link with a filter in it?
I'm really pulling my hair out right now :(

Comment: *{{ ('service?subject=' ~ product.code  ~ '&message=' ~ ('Desired amount' | t) | url_encode) | url }}* should work.

Comment: @RSez: Offcourse forgot the `''`... thx man!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

configure a route:

```
# example
acme_demo_service:
    path: /service
    defaults:
        _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Test:service
```

Use [url](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#url) function:

```
{% set link = url('acme_demo_service', {'subject':product.code, 'message':'Desired amount'|trans}) %}
{{ link }}
```